# loading message + redirection after form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form with a unique `<input type="text">`. I call a php file, but I make a lot of checks (checking if the file exists, I call many APIs...), so the result is very long to come.

Thus, I'm looking for a script (jquery,ajax,....) doing many things :

1. the form is submit, and the php file is called
2. showing a pending/loading message (or progressbar)
3. redirect the user to a new page when all the php is done

I searched on all the github directory, without success.

How to do this? Is there a plugin doing that?

A similar example : http://www.statduck.com/

Comment: first do research and post your code here. What you have tried before?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$.post(url, {FormData: $('#TheFormTagID').serialize()},
        function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {                   
            alert(data); //will alert "Something"
            window.location.href = "your new page";
        },
        "json")
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        { 
            alert("Error: " + textStatus);
        });
```

In PHP just use: `$_POST["FormData"]` to get Form variables and in the end of the PHP script `echo "Something";` to get result in Javascript.

Maybe some useful stuff: [link](http://brian.staruk.me/php/2013/sample-jquery-php-ajax-script/)

**Edited:**

Let's say this is PHP:

```
//Save file
//do something other
$result = new stdClass();
$result->ID = 5;
$result->FileName = "Test.jpg";
echo json_encode($result);  
?>
```

Then in Javascript `function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)` use this values like this:

```
function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {                   
            alert(data.ID); //will alert 5
            alert(data.FileNa,e); //will alert Test.jpg

        }
```

Comment: Thank you Makla, the script in your link is very useful.
However, I don't know of to change this code to integrate the redirection to the new page if it's successful ?
is-it possible to do that with this script ?

Comment: I don't know if I understand you completely, but I hope Edited post helps.

Comment: Yes, thank you Makla !  I finished to make the script !

Comment: Great. Could you please mark it for answer if it helps you and if it answer your question.